# Better way to write this code?

Tags: python, idioms

I have the following code and I think it stinks because of repetition of `vi`. How can I write it better?

```
vi = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)'

handlers = [
    (r'/register', RegistrationHandler),
    (r'/profiles/%s/%s' % (vi, vi), GetProfiles),
    (r'/archives/%s/%s/%s/%s' % (vi, vi, vi, vi), GetArchives),
    (r'/publish-profiles', PublishProfiles),
    (r'/publish-bundle/%s/%s' % (vi, vi), PublishBundle),
    (r'/upload-file/%s/%s/%s' % (vi, vi, vi), UploadFile),
    (r"/favicon\.ico", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path=settings['static_path'])),
    ]
```

Comment: I don't find suggestions in the answers better than the OP's code.

Comment: also, you can simplify `vi` to `([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)` or just `[\w.-]`.

Comment: @thg435, sorry it didn't work. I have dashes and dots to take care of.

Comment: To the person who voted to close: _"but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."_ Nothing of that sort has happened, and I see little likelihood of that happening any time. Why not try something else to vent out your personal life frustrations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on Python 2.6+ you can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
r'/archives/{0}/{0}/{0}/{0}'.format(vi)
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks even better than what @ted suggested.

Comment: Or, to combine with @ted's answer `r'/archives/{vi}/{vi}/{vi}/{vi}'.format(vi=vi)`

Answer (score 6):

Thats easy, try naming your variables, you can then access a variable with a given name, any number of times. Here is an example:

```
"%(vi)s is %(vi)s" % {'vi':vi}
```

Basically you use a dict for the replacement. You then change you formatstings from `%<options><variabletype>` (e.g. `%2s`) to `%(<dictKey><options><variabletype>)` (e.g. `%(vi)2s`)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a tuple with `n` repetitions of `vi` you can write `(vi,)*n`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can avoid having to specify the number of `vi`s altogether?